# how to maintain a SharePoint server?

Tags: 2007, windows-server, backup, best-practices

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 + Windows Server 2008. I want to know whether there are any existing best practices or tools to maintain a SharePoint server, for example how to monitor SharePoint Server issues and backup SharePoint Server application (both code and data)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some info on MS TechNet that covers some of the options and the limitations of each:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/bb736212.aspx

I would read through that and figure out specifically what you would like to do and how often you need to do it.  For a system of any size, I really like what some of the third-party tools provide for backup and recovery with item-level granularity.

Here is a book I would recommend if you are really intersted in digging deep:  [http://www.amazon.com/SharePoint-2007-Disaster-Recovery-Guide/dp/1584505990](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584505990)

In addition, here is an aritcle with some key concepts I covered in a few presentations about creating a DR plan:  http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2010/02/keys-to-establishing-disaster-recovery.html